# How I can import Code Style from WebStorm to Visual Studio Code?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, visual-studio-code

I want to share TypeScript Code Style settings. I can export them from `File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript` in a JSON or XML format from WebStorm. 
Is it possible to import the settings into a VScode somehow?

Comment: Check this out it might give you a hint: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915970/how-to-export-all-my-intellij-code-styles-to-a-editorconfig-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915970/how-to-export-all-my-intellij-code-styles-to-a-editorconfig-file)

Comment: form injellij forum : that there is no way at the moment, to create same code style environment between two IDEAs by exporting settings from IDEA into VSCode or vice versa.

Comment: Have you found away to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S), go to Editor | Code Style, select the desired scheme from the list, and click the Show Scheme Actions button.

Select one of the following options:

Copy to IDE: select this option to store the selected scheme in the global level.

WebStorm saves the new code style with the specified name to the config/codestyles/<code_style_name>.xml file under the WebStorm home directory.

Copy to Project: select this option to store the selected scheme in the project level.

The selected code style is saved to: .idea/codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml.

Duplicate: select this option to make a copy of the selected scheme and store it in the same level.

In the Scheme field, type the name of the new scheme and press Enter to save the changes.

Apply changes and close the dialog.