# How to set "Editor > Code Style > Java" parameters from Intellij by .editorconfig file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, editorconfig

Ok! I can set rules of formatting by putting an *.editorconfig* file in the root path of the project. But how can I set the *"Editor > Code Style > Java"* using this *.editorconfig* file?

**In other words, what I need is to know how to import this file to config the Code Style section.**

I need this to updated *.editorconfig* when necessary.

[image]

Comment: Since your question is about _importing_ the `.editorconfig` file into
 IntelliJ and the question [How to export all Intellij code styles to a
 .editorconfig file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35915970) is about
 _exporting_ `.editorconfig`, I concluded that your question is not a
 duplicate of that other question. | I have changed my mind though,
 now thinking that this question _is_ a duplicate of the other one.
~ * ~
I might get back to explain why I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't. The settings defined in .editorconfig are not visible in the CTRL+ALT+S - Code style.
we have just the message
"Settings may be overriden by EditorConfig"

Comment: That is the answer I feared most! But I was already expecting it! XD

Comment: I hate that this is the answer, but this does seem to be correct :(

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.editorconfig` in project and the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | **Enable EditorConfig support** option is enabled IDE will take code style options from `.editorconfig` file (if it exists) instead of from the Editor | **Code Style** IDE settings.

To see and control the options for `Code Style > Java` you can by exporting your current IDE Code Style setting to `.editorconfig` file:

[image]

and see and change them under the `[*.java]` section in the file.

Comment: I know how to export an .editorconfig. What I need is to know how to import this file to config the Code Style section.